# Unable to Extract Keys have special Characters in MySQL using JSON_EXTRACT

Tags: mysql, json

i have a json field in my table(MySQL Database).

the following is the structure:

```
{
    "article":{
            "Key's 1":{
                "value":"24"
            }
            "Key's of the something's 2":{
                "value":"55"
            }
    }

}
```

i am trying to extract the **"value"** field of **"Key's 1"**.

Due special character such as **single quote** and **space**, i am unable use JSON_EXTRACT function.

It give the error: Invalid JSON path expression.This error is around character position no : 10

My Query:

```
select 
    JSON_EXTRACT(analytics_json,'$.article.Key\'s 1.value')As value
from
    tbl_json_data;
```

Even after place a **backslash**, i am getting the error.

Answer (score 7):

You may escape each JSON path component in double quotes to handle special characters as well as spaces.  The following works:

```
SELECT 
    JSON_EXTRACT(analytics_json,'$.article."Key''s 1".value') AS value
FROM tbl_json_data;
```

### Demo

Note that your key name actually has *two* problems.  First, it contains a literal single quote.  We can handle that by just doubling up two single quotes.  The key name also contains whitespace.  By escaping in double quotes we may workaround this problem, but it would probably be best to avoid using JSON keys which have whitespace.

Comment: Wish I could upvote this a dozen times, thanks!